# Convert one case class to another by using selected element

Tags: scala

Want to retrieve specific element from the input class while making the list of an output case class.

Example :

```
case class Student(id:Int, grade:Int, marks:Int)
case class StudentID(id:Int,grade:Int)


val inputList= Option[List(Student(1,100,234) ,Student(2,200,453), Student(3,300,556))]
val outputList=List(StudentID(1,100),StudentID(2,200),StudentID(3,300)) //result
```

I am trying to get only the id and grade. Please suggest.
Also, the problem is input list is `Option[]`.

```
val a = inputList.iterator.flatMap{ i=> outputList(i.map(_.id)) }
```

Comment: `inputList.map(student => StudentID(student.id))`

Comment: Can you be clearer on what you are actually trying to do? Do you just want to extract the student IDs, or look them up in `outputList` as well?

Comment: this should work `val res = inputList.map(s => StudentID(s.id))`

Comment: But what if in input there are 3 elements and in output in need to use only 2 . should i use case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the transition from `Student`-to-`StudentID` occurs at multiple places throughout the code base, then it might make sense to put the translation logic in the companion object.

```
case class Student(id:Int, grade:Int, marks:Int)
case class StudentID(id:Int,grade:Int)
object StudentID {
  def apply(s: Student) = new StudentID(s.id, s.grade)
}

val inputList= 
  Option(List(Student(1,100,234) ,Student(2,200,453), Student(3,300,556)))

inputList.map(_.map(StudentID(_)))
//res0: Option[List[StudentID]] =
//  Some(List(StudentID(1,100), StudentID(2,200), StudentID(3,300)))
```

Answer (score 3):

The question is still not clear, but I think this is the code you want:

```
inputList.map(_.map(s => StudentID(s.id, s.grade))).getOrElse(Nil)
```

The outer `map` and `getOrElse(Nil)` deal with the fact that the input is an `Option[List]` not just `List`. The inner `map` converts each element of the input `List` from `Student` to `StudentID`.

Comment: If you did `getOrElse` first, you would not need to nest the `map` call in another `map`

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that you use any of the many available case class mapping libraries.

Some examples:

- [chimney](https://github.com/scalalandio/chimney)
- [henkan](https://github.com/kailuowang/henkan)
- [automapper](https://github.com/bfil/scala-automapper)

You could also write your own solution with shapeless or macros, but it's not worth it since there are already working solutions.

Example with chimney:

```
import io.scalaland.chimney.dsl._

inputList match {
  case Some(l) => l.map(s => s.into[StudentID].transform)
  case None => Nil
}
```

Alternatively, you could just manually map one case class to another, but it can get tedious with case classes with many fields.